# Multiple Value of a javascript argument

Tags: javascript, android, json, arguments, infobip-api

I am working with a Javascript function to send one single message to multiple destinations or numbers:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "from": "InfoSMS",
  "to": [
    "41793026727",
    "41793026834"
  ],
  "text": "Test SMS."
});
```

Now in my app I made "to" as an argument- arg.receivers where the numbers will be fed to the code as 41793026727,41793026834

However the argument-arg.receivers is recognized as a single number argument so it doesn't send the SMS

So if the arg.receivers is just one number for eg. 41793026834 it sends the SMS but if it is multiple like the above it does not send it.

it there a way to frame the argument as multiple numbers?

please help

Comment: How are you sending and receiving these messages?

Comment: @gurvinder372 var data = JSON.stringify({
  "from": "InfoSMS",
  "to": [
    "41793026727",
    "41793026834"
  ],
  "text": "Test SMS."
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = false;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

Comment: @gurvinder372 second part xhr.open("POST", "https://api.infobip.com/sms/1/text/single");
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
xhr.send(data);

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate data (don't stringify) and send messages one by one.

```js
var data = {
  "from": "InfoSMS",
  "to": ["41793026727", "41793026834"],
  "text": "Test SMS."
};

data.to.forEach( function(to){
   sendMessage( JSON.stringify( Object.assign( {}, {to:to}, data )  ) ); //creating one message each for **to**
});

function sendMessage(data) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = false;
  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  });
  xhr.open("POST", "api.infobip.com/sms/1/text/single");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
  xhr.send(data);
}
```

**Edit**

If you are already getting a string then do

```
data = JSON.parse( data );
```

and then proceed with rest of the logic from `forEach`

Comment: @FiifiDes did you forgot to remove `stringify` for `data`.

Comment: @FiifiDes Just don't use it, or if your input is already stringified, then do `JSON.parse(str)` to get back the object.

Comment: @FiifiDes No! As I have mentioned before either don't do stringify as you were doing earlier or use JSON.parse to get back the object from string.

Comment: @FiifiDes Sorry, I didn't understood how your last comment relates to the question.

Comment: You can get it by doing `obj.contact`

Comment: Why do you want to make a variable?

Comment: At this point, can you share a working fiddle or a snippet demonstrating your issue?

Comment: can you provide an email so i can send via email?

Comment: can you provide an email so send a video via email?